# Screen does not updat while using react hook, unless I reload the app

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I am trying to login in my user with email and password. If the user has entered his credentials correctly, I use AsyncStorage to update the authentication status to "true".

In my main App.js file I check the AsyncStorage, to see whether the auth status if "true" or false. The problem is when the user logs in and AsyncStorage gets updated the screen does not get updated unless i refresh the app, (using fastreload).

### What i essentially need is a way to re-render or re-run the code in App.js without the user closing the app and then re-opening it.

Here's what I am doing

```
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").then((val) =>
    val == "true" ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false)
  );

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

}

What should I do, so that my app redirects the user as soon as the "auth" changes to "true"

Comment: How do they authenticate in the child components? You might need to pass in a callback method for them to notify the App that the auth has changed. AsyncStorage doesn't have a listener functionality iirc

Comment: I suggest that you use global state or state conainer like [reducx](https://redux.js.org/introduction/core-concepts) or [context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html), other wise you're gonna go for massive prop drilling

Comment: Not necessarily - simply prop drilling one component is way better than setting up a global state solution for something as simple at this - not every project needs redux!

Answer (score 0):

Try using AsyncStorage inside useEffect hook

```
useEffect(() => {
  AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").then((val) =>
  val == "true" ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false)
);
}, []);
```

Comment: This won't work as this would only run on first render, which they already have. They need a way of updating it after the "auth" item has been changed, which this does not do.

Comment: I need the code to re render after i change the state in async-storage

Answer (score 0):

The `AsyncStorage` [API docs](https://react-native-community.github.io/async-storage/docs/api) don't show a nice change-listener functionality, so you can either try to poll the storage repeatedly to see if it has changed (not nice), or you can make a notifying callback function that updates the state when called, and pass that function through as a prop to be called in your child component when the authentication happens.

```
export default function App() {
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

  const checkAuthentication = () => {
    AsyncStorage.getItem("auth").then((val) =>
      val == "true" ? setIsAuthenticated(true) : setIsAuthenticated(false)
    );
  };

  useEffect(checkAuthentication, []);

  return isAuthenticated ? (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none" initialRouteName="Home">
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Orders" component={Orders} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  ) : (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator headerMode="none">
        <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={Welcome} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Login" component={Login} authChanged={checkAuthentication} />
        <Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} authChanged={checkAuthentication} />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

The `useEffect` will run the check on your first page load, and then in the `Login` and `Signup` components, make them call their `authChanged` prop function when the login state has changed. That will cause the state to be updated.